# How to prevent qmake from adding the console subsystem on the linker command line?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

qmake is putting both `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` and `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` on the linker command line. This is in spite of having `CONFIG += windows` and `CONFIG -= console` present in the project file. This is with Qt 5.1.1, `app` template, otherwise default settings. The mkscpec is win32-msvc2012. I'm using the `widgets` and `testlib` subsystems.

How do I get rid of the `CONSOLE` subsystem?

Comment: Actually, here the question is more useful to me than the anwser...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qt 5 using `testlib` module adds a `console` option via the `MODULE_CONFIG` mechanism. This forces a `/SUBSYSTEM: CONSOLE` onto the linker command line no matter what global options you specify, even if you use `CONFIG -= console`.

The `console` configuration is given in the testlib module configuration within `qtbase/src/testlib/testlib.pro`. This means that it [ends up in `QT.testlib.CONFIG` variable](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Creating-a-new-module-or-tool-for-Qt#58bc93114d2386b74e861888ac36a384).
 It's easily removable if you want to use `testlib` without forcing the console subsystem. In your project file, add

```
QT.testlib.CONFIG -= console
```